# Mapping A number not divisible by 10 to UIProgressview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I am working on an iPhone app utilizing two UIProgressviews. The problem is that it is quite simple to show the progress of something 5/100 or 5/10 but in order to show something 5/16 I would need to change the maximum value of the progress view. I can't seem to find a (I think it's called) property of progress views that I could use with it. For example something like .maximumValue. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: int MAXVALUE = 16; progressView.progress = 5/MAXVALUE;

Comment: @lakesh That will set `progress` to zero because you're performing integer division.

Comment: @robmayoff thanks. Made a mistake as well.

Comment: What ist the problem here? `.property` is a `float` anyway, a sort of procentual value between 0 and 1, similar to the `.alpha` property of `UIView` or each color component value when creating an `UIColor` from rgb values. Just make sure that it is really a float and not an int caluclation. Devide by `16.0f` if it is a constant or assign it to a float or use the `floatValue` method of an `NSNumber`. (Strictly spoken `16f` or `16.0` should do, but `16.0f` is rather conventional.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIProgressView` `progress` property varies from 0 (meaning no progress at all) to 1 (meaning everything is done).

So:

```
self.progressView.progress = 5.0 / 16.0;
```

Or, to animate to the new progress:

```
[self.progressView setProgress:5.0/16.0 animated:YES];
```

Technically, the `progress` property is a `float`, so you could say `5.0f / 16.0f` to save a few nanoseconds.  But you are probably not updating the property often enough for this to matter.

Answer (score 3):

UIProgressView's progress property stands from 0 to 1.

So its require to divide as per your maximum value.

For example, if in application, there is `maximum value is 23` then code should be like this:

```
float progressValue = <Actual Value> / 23.0;

[myProgressView setProgress: progreassValue];
```

Refer [UIProgressView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

As ProgressView `progress` property is of type float, you can use type casting as follows :

```
int value=5;
int MaxValue=15;
float Progress=(float)value/MaxValue;
[self.myProgressview setProgress:Progress animated:YES];
```